# R LDAvis K=2 createJSON() error

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I was using LDAvis package's createJSON() function while my topicmodel was for 2 topics and received this error

```
Error in stats::cmdscale(dist.mat, k = 2) : 'k' must be in {1, 2, .. n - 1}
```

Then I tested with reproducible example given [here](http://cpsievert.github.io/LDAvis/reviews/reviews.html), by putting K=2 and keeping everything same and bumped into this error again in createJSON().

Upon looking at the source code of createJSON() [here](https://github.com/cpsievert/LDAvis/blob/master/R/createJSON.R), the issue is in function jsPCA().
In jsPCA(), while K=2, the dist.mat comes out to be a single value which throws an error in line

```
pca.fit <- stats::cmdscale(dist.mat, k = 2)
```

Any advice how to get past this error?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Please share.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem comes up because of a division by zero issue with the jensenShannon function that sits inside of jsPCA.  The entire jsPCA code looks like this:

```
 jsPCA <- function(phi){
    jensenShannon <- function(x, y) {
    m <- 0.5 * (x + y)
    0.5 * sum(x * log(x/m)) + 0.5 * sum(y * log(y/m))
    }
    dist.mat <- proxy::dist(x = phi, method = jensenShannon)
    pca.fit <- stats::cmdscale(dist.mat, k = 2)
    data.frame(x = pca.fit[, 1], y = pca.fit[, 2])  
    }
```

If m contains zeros, the result is NaN.  The errors trickle through from there.  So, you can prevent the error by specifying a dimensionality-reduction method that tolerates zeros. Indeed, the LDAvis documentation provides an option rooted in t-SNE:

```
 library("tsne")
 svd_tsne <- function(x) tsne(svd(x)$u)
```

Simply plug this function into mds.method, and you should be good to go:

```
 createJSON(phi, theta, doc.length, vocab, term.frequency,
            mds.method = svd_tsne,
            plot.opts = list(xlab="", ylab="")
            )
```